# Javascript slideshow array issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I'm pretty new to Javascript and im trying to build slideshow myself now. Only im stuck right now after i build the array where i get my pictures from. It only shows a white screen.

My Javascript

```
 $(function () {
var counter = 0;
var defaultSettings = {
    "sliderContainer": "#slider"
    , "pauseWithMouse": true
    , "sliderSpeed": 2000
    , "transitionSpeed": 1500
};

function cycleImages() {
    counter++;
if (counter >= images.Length) {
    counter = 0;
}
document.getElementById("#slider img").src = MyImages[counter];

var images = $('#slider img')
    , now = images.filter(':visible')
    , next = now.next().length ? now.next() : images.first()
    , speed = 1500; //Transition speed
now.fadeOut(speed);
next.fadeIn(speed);
 }

var theInterval; // Slide speed

var = images = [];
// if myImages exists then
images = myImages;
if (images.length > 0) {
    $(defaultSettings.sliderContainer).append('<img id="sliderImage" src="' + images[0] + '" />');
    startSlide();
}
var startSlide = function () {
    setInterval(cycleImages, defaultSettings.sliderSpeed); // Set interval
};
var stopSlide = function () {
    if (defaultSettings.pauseWithMouse) {
        clearInterval(theInterval);
    }
};
startSlide();
$('#slider img').on('mouseover', function () {
    stopSlide();
});
$('#slider img').on('mouseout', function () {
    startSlide();
});
});
```

And my HTML:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Javascript Slider</title>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="js/slideshow.js"></script>

<script>
  var myImages = ["slide1.jpg", "slide2.jpg", "bg/slide3.jpg"];
 </script>
</head>

<body>
<main>
<div id="slider">
</div>
</main> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide fiddle or sample to run your code?

Comment: yes: https://jsfiddle.net/xr6sfdyj/

Comment: Ok not sure if this is your problem, but you declare `var images = $('#slider img')` and then like 4 lines later you declare `var images = []` Did you mean to do that? And pointing out the obvious here, change `var = images = []` to `var images = []`

Comment: Yes thanks it shows the first image now, but still not sliding

Comment: You did not address the biggest point I made. You have 2 var's named `images`. I assume you need different names for them, why would you override it 4 lines after if otherwise? Can you fix your code to not have the same variable name? That might be your biggest problem, I see numerous ones though.

Answer (score 1):

1. you have strange declaration of variable here

   var = images = [];
2. also you need to move this part

   ```
   var startSlide = function() {
     setInterval(cycleImages, defaultSettings.sliderSpeed); // Set interval
   };
   ```

   before

   ```
   if (images.length > 0) {
     $(defaultSettings.sliderContainer).append('<img id="sliderImage" src="' + images[0] + '" />');
     startSlide();
   }
   ```
3. you have wrong variable name (MyImages) here

   ```
   document.getElementById("#slider img").src = MyImages[counter];
   ```

first try to debug your code

Comment: It's impossible for any of us to answer seeing as the OP has 2 var named `images` and we have no idea which var hes trying to reference at any part of the code. There's numerous problems with the code, and before he fixes the 2 `images` problem we cant possibly have any idea how to fix the rest of the code.

Comment: first var images is inside function i think it will not conflict
i think author can press F12 and see what errors he receives in console

Comment: Console says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Length' of undefined at CycleImages

Comment: in function cycleImages you are getting length of variable images which is not yet defined. if you are planning to receive it then you need to change your function like this

    function cycleImages(images) {
then you need to change this one

    var startSlide = function (images) {
      setInterval(cycleImages(images), defaultSettings.sliderSpeed); // Set 
interval
    };

as well also calls of start slide, but after this i see that you will face other error, so try to work on code bugfixing. you need to spend some time